# How to check free slots available in RabbitMQ 's queue for a range of time interval?

Tags: rabbitmq, gmail-api

I am working on GMail API. I can send bulk email at once using the Gmail APIs. However now, I need to schedule the mails in different time intervals instead of sending the all the mail at once.

This service of control deliverability of mail is not provided by the Gmail API. So for that I am using the services of rabbitMQ and creating a queue and then enqueuing the mails into it.  While enqueuing , I must provide the delay such that it fits the free slot availability and also the mails are distributed equally among free slots and time intervals.

Currently I am struck at how to find available free slots in the queue.

I have gone through the RabbitMQ - Monitoring Documentations and only relevant thing which I could found is :-[Response of queue details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaqF0.png.)

but still I am clueless how to deduct the free available slots for a particular time interval. Help me to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this issue seams to be related to Rabbit MQ not Gmail.  Do we need the gmail tag?

Comment: I feel we need that because  who knows, someone may suggest another approach to do the same task.

Comment: I cant say that i have tried what you are doing it is an interesting approach.  What you need to remember about rabbit is that as soon as something is on the queue if you read it it is removed from the queue.   That being said the only way you are going to know what a free spot is is if you are storing the times you added them in your system some place.   if you are doing that already then i wonder if it wouldn't just be better to have your scheduler in a database rather then RabbitMQ.

Comment: If you check [rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange)  I think you will find no mention of being able to check for time availability probably because this is not something that would be supported by Rabbit itself.

Comment: I have worked with the Gmail API for more then ten years.  If i was going to make this type of system I would have this in a database.   I would set up a microservice to poll for messages and send them off when it finds one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no feature in GMail API to “schedule” an email to be sent. However there is a [long standing Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140922183) for that.

Regarding RabbitMQ, I don’t think a message queue is meant to work that way, I’d recommend implementing your own take to that approach of a pool of tasks.

For example, having a centralized list of tasks (like a relational DB table) that would have minimal information about:

- Type of task to be executed (`send email` for example)
- Time frame to be executed (`Daily | 14:00-16:00` or `2022-02-03 | 14:00-16:00` for example)
- Callback context data (`{recipient: “a@a.com”, body:”Hello World!”}` for example)

A scheduler service that is responsible for adding tasks to this queue/pool table can have a method like `findATime()` or `listAvailableSpotsForTheDay()`.